# Grönwall-type upper bound

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, upper-lower-bounds

I'm having a hard time showing that this lemma is true:

> Suppose $h\geq 0$ is a continuous non-increasing function on $[0,T]$, $f$ is continuous on $[0,T]$, and $g\geq 0$ is integrable on $[0,T]$. If
> $$f(t) \geq h(t) - \int_0^t g(s)f(s) \, ds$$
> for all $t\in [0,T]$, then
> $$f(t) \geq h(t)e^{-\int_0^t g(s) \, ds},$$
> for all $t\in [0,T]$.

If you change "non-increasing" to "non-decreasing," the $\geq$ signs to $\leq$ signs, and the minus signs to positives (in both the hypothesis and the conclusion), then you have the standard Grönwall inequality, which I can prove using essentially the same proof that's on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality) under "Integral Form for Continuous Functions." This initially made me try to use something like $\overline{f}=-f$ and apply the standard Grönwall inequality, but I couldn't get the result to come out.

The problem is that the standard proof strategy does not seem to work out for the above reversed Grönwall inequality since I always end up with the inequality going the wrong direction at the end. I could even get by if I replaced the function $h(t)$ with a constant, but cannot seem to prove it in that case either. Does anyone know how to prove this statement (or, know of a counterexample)?

I would be happy to add more details about what proof strategies I've tried if that would help. I haven't been able to find any reference or web page that mentions this type of inequality anywhere, so even a reference would be appreciated!

EDIT: It seems that the statement may not be true, but I have not found a counterexample. I was able to get around the issue by proving a similar differential inequality:

> Suppose $f>0$ is differentiable and $g\geq 0$ is integrable, both on on $[0,T]$. If
> $$f'(t) \geq -g(t)f(t)$$
> for all $t \in [0,T]$, then
> $$f(t) \geq f(0)e^{-\int_0^t g(s) \, ds}$$
> for all $t \in [0,T]$.

Comment: I have introduced the tag "functional inequalities" and erased the "pde" tag ; no connection here with partial differential equations.

Comment: Thank you. I added the PDE tag since that's where this kind of thing would be used, but you're right.

Comment: About the tags : "pde" OK, I understand. OK also for the large domain of "real-analysis", but I insist for keeping as well the much narrower "functional inequalities". Think to people who will be, later on, querying on analogous issues, without  knowing the existence of Mr Gronwall, your question will be selected in this way.

Comment: Are you sure it ain't $g \le 0$? Because then you have Grönwall.

Comment: I'm sure it's supposed to be $\geq 0$. I'm reading through a preprint of a paper that presents this lemma without proof, and the lemma is definitely used with $g\geq 0$. I'm sure the author would not want me sharing the preprint here, unfortunately. 

It seems this lemma is used in fluid mechanics with the unofficial name "reverse Gronwall inequality" but it's been eluding any of my attempts at proving it (I was told it is a simple proof that mirrors the proof of Gronwall, but I am doubting this now).

Comment: I am not saying it is wrong, but the statement looks suspect. If you change $f$ with $-f$ you have Gronwall inequality except for a swapped sign for $g$. Essentially what it is argued here is fully equivalent equivalent to say that the assumption of positivity of $g$ is not necessary for the Gronwall Lemma.